# Access an html tag from the code behind in MVC3

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3, intellisense, code-behind

I'm attempting to merge two projects in visual studios 2008

The project I am trying to bring in is styled like the old school asp.net projects using the code behind setups to access the on page load methods and so on, but the other projects is the new fangled MVC3 styled project.

Now I am fully aware that these two projects are mapped differently for access and most likely shouldn't be put together, but if i listened to every thing i was told not to do, i wouldn't have the bad ass tattoo of an angel eating a hot dog on my left ass cheek.

Now when I talk about merging these two together all I'm really talking about is bring in 1 view of .aspx type into my MVC3 project and making it run along side the other views that are there. I have been able to bring it in, I have a function in a controller setup for it and I have it's code behind there linked in properly, every thing seems to be a go, but intellisense doesn't recognize that the html tags that have an id and a runat server property on them are going to be objects in my code behind. It keeps telling me to declare these variables.

For shits and giggles I did try declaring them, at which point intellisense smiled and gave me a wink before dashing my hopes against a sharp rock by alerting me that the variables had all ready been declared when the page was parsed.

**Edit:** The controller is performing it's own tasks, as I stated above the code behind is handling the page load function and in the old setup the you could directly access any html tags that used the runat server propertie, I'm trying to duplicate this along side MVC3, I'm not trying to put it all in the controller. So to clear it up, I have a Model, View, controller, then inside my view i have my aspx page with a code page named filename.aspx.cs, does that help?

**Edit2:** OK for this setup like i said above were using vs2008 so it has the view model and controller folders where you place your three separate areas I have a particular view from another project that was using the old code behind approach of attaching a code file to a .aspx file by using the CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" parameter, so I pulled this .aspx file with it's code behind file from the old project and stuck it into the new MVC3 project and told them to coexist much like a an adult tells a child not to stick something in there mouth(just cause you tell em to doesn't mean there gonna). but the old code behind file uses a page load function that has to initialize some html tags from a certain library but i of course can't access these tags, and they don't have html helpers or any thing cool like that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By convention, there should be no code behind in MVC. A great place to start is http://www.asp.net/mvc.

Comment: And if I were you, I would start doing what I was told :)

Comment: I'm fully aware of this, but i can only get this view as an old project and it needs access to these tags, i would love to get rid of this codebehind, but i can't figure out how to access these tags from the controller, because as David said below, the controller "it knows nothing about the view"

Comment: Putting an ASPX file in a folder called Views doesn't make it a view.  Honestly, and this is especially exemplified in your recent edit, the entire premise is flawed.  Your approach seems based on "I think it would be cool and clever to do this, so I'm going to do this" as opposed to "This is the right tool for the job and a solid, supportable design."  Use WebForms.  Or use MVC.  Or mix both properly (different "pages" implemented in the different paradigms, separate from one another). What you're trying to do is, in every way, _wrong_. One paradigm is not a drop-in replacement for the other.

Comment: I know this, I am aware that what i'm doing is weird, i am aware that you can't just drop it in, i didn't think i would need to go into detail about how i applied this older aspx file to make it recognized as a view. and this isn't a i think it would be cool if scenario, i'm legitimately trying to get these two to cooperate. with each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, all i needed to do to access these tags was use the FindControl() function, in side the code behind file, it was that simple, the thing runs like a champ now.
So what i had was a view with a control like

```
<button id="foo" runat="server">
```

then of course i had a controller with the function

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Return View();
}
```

and lastly I have the code behind which contains

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Button)This.FindControl("foo")).DoSomething();    
}
```

Easy peasy lemon squeezy.

thanks for the help any way guys

Answer (score 3):

This isn't how MVC works.  From the perspective of the controller, it knows *nothing* about the view.  There isn't a bi-directional communication between them, they don't derive from a single base (like WebForms does), etc.  The controller action performs some logic, builds a viewmodel (optionally), and sends that viewmodel (optionally) to the view.  One way, no going back.

So instead of something like this:

```
TextBox1.Text = "foo";
```

You'd do something like this in the controller action:

```
myViewModel.SomeTextField = "foo";
```

Then, in the view, you'd access that value on the viewmodel:

```
@Html.TextBox("name", Model.SomeTextField)
```

The controller should never, *must* never be bound to a view.  By design, action methods can pass control to any view you want.  They're not bound to a "page" like in WebForms.

It's a separation of concerns, an inversion of control, all that good stuff.  The controller builds an object and sends it to *a* view, any view, doesn't matter which one.  The view expects a viewmodel from *a* controller, any controller, doesn't matter which one.

Comment: The controller is performing it's own tasks, as I stated above the code behind is handling the page load function and in the old setup the you could directly access any html tags that used the runat server propertie, I'm trying to duplicate this along side MVC3, I'm not trying to put it all in the controller. So to clear it up, I have a Model, View, controller, then inside my view i have my aspx page with a code page named filename.aspx.cs, does that help?

Comment: @Warped: I'm not sure what you mean by "inside my view i have my aspx page with a code page".  Can you create a small example to illustrate this and post it in the question?  From the sound of this comment, it feels like you're trying to combine the two paradigms in unnatural ways, which will result in something which is neither MVC nor WebForms (and will be a nightmare to maintain).

Comment: Nightmare yes!, but I won't have to maintain it once I have this working it's good to go, and doesn't have to be touched again. I will give some more insight into my particular problem above. but creating an example is hard to do because of how odd the setup is.

Comment: @Warped: Be aware of a few points in that comment... "doesn't have to be touched again" - In my experience, this is a lie.  Software needs to be maintained.  _Never_ design software with the assumption that it won't be maintained.  "hard to do because of how odd the setup is" - This is an indication that you're going about it the wrong way.  Favor simplicity.  Use the tools the way they're supposed to be used.  And so on.

Comment: I can't, the other view only comes in as the old style asp.net project.